With the transition from SDK 49 to 51 my project crush
With the transition from SDK 49 to 51, almost everything crashed. Errors on Google Maps constantly appear, and the map itself stopped displaying, although I use Expo.
react-native-maps: AirGoogleMaps dir must be added to your xCode project to support GoogleMaps on iOS.
And also these errors:
ERROR Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()? TypeError: Invalid character in header content ["X-React-Native-Project-Root"] at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:651:3) Warning: Barcode: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
Error on Android:
 TypeError: Invalid character in header content ["X-React-Native-Project-Root"] at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:651:3)
On Android, the application simply doesn't start. I tried to use the advice from GitHub at this link, but it still didn't work. Additionally, when I follow the advice and edit the URL, the application stops launching on iOS as well.
https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/2279
